# Why am I unable to choose default settings for media streaming options?

Tags: windows-7, streaming

I have a desktop running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. When I click on "**Choose default settings...**" in *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Media streaming options*, nothing happens. I believe an option dialog should pop up.

[image: Media streamin options]

What is wrong with my system?

Answer (score 0):

you are correct. This is the popup that you should get when clicking Choose default settings...

[image: choose default settings popup]

Although I don't know what could it be wrong, or how it can be fixed. Sorry.